# Метод replace в тексте

Tags: python

Не могу понять, почему не происходит замена каждой гласной буквы на другую рандомную гласную в тексте.

```
import random

string = "лбфвалоывралыврагшунедшгцуеролываобфивлалоиаі ваівлаоиігвдариі афіафіа фі а фі а ф іа фі а філ аоююь"
ad = ['у', 'е', 'а', 'о', 'і', 'и', 'є']
h = random.choice(ad)
for i in string:
    for j in i:
        try:
            assert j in ad
            i.replace(j, h)
        except:
            continue
print(string)
```

Comment: for j in i: - это у вас что призвано делать?

Comment: пройти каждую букву слова

Comment: Слова? Вы строку на слова не разбиваете в вашем коде...

Comment: метод replace не изменяет текущую строку, а порождает новую полученную в результате замены.

Comment: как это реализовать?

Comment: Ох и сложно все у вас! `''.join([random.choice(ad) if x in ad else x for x in string])`

Comment: Спасибо ! А как сделать,чтобы  каждая гласная менялась на другую? Так как из списка может рандомиться та же самая буква

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, добавил в виде ответа... Кстати `ю` у вас согласная? ;-)

Comment: Забыл,спасибо!:)

Comment: А, еще проблема в том, что большие буквы не меняются, а если их в список добавить, то большие будут менять маленькие. Как поступить?

Comment: Вы можете уточнить вопрос? Что вам надо получить? И приведите воспроизводимый пример пожалуйста...

Comment: Все работает верно,но не меняются большие гласные буквы.Если я большие добавлю в список ad, то выведется такое:




> Влесню кАжачА, щирЮкО "Вiдкруття пОливоння" бєвеА двiчi: >пЮршуге сарпня
> нО  птацА,  і  пюршюга  лустепедА  нЮ  звiро,

Comment: Нужно, чтоб большие гласные менялись на большие гласные, а маленькие -на маленькие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = """Катерино, серце моє!
Лишенько з тобою!
Де ти в світі подінешся
З малим сиротою?
Хто спитає, привітає
Без милого в світі?
Батько, мати — чужі люде,
Тяжко з ними жити!"""

def f(s):
    vowels = set('аоуіиеяюєї')
    res = []
    for x in s:
        if x.lower() not in vowels:
            res.append(x)
            continue
        c = random.choice(list(vowels - set(x.lower())))
        res.append(c.upper() if x.isupper() else c)
    return ''.join(res)
```

Пример:

```
In [184]: print(f(s))
Кутюрюнє, сюрцо мїи!
Лєшїнькя з тибяи!
Ди тя в святї падунішси
З мюлем сїрєтиє?
Хту спотяе, прувятея
Баз мєлагу в свато?
Бїтькі, мєте — чиже лідє,
Тожкї з наму жєте!
```

Comment: все-таки большие буквы не меняет)

[In]: print(swap_glasn("Атаман ура победа"))
[Out]:Атюмян иря пебєдю

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, подправил - попробуйте сейчас...

Comment: Всё хорошо, благодарю :b